# Program to find two non-repeating numbers in an array

Tags: java, c++

I don't know about the vector class of int but why this code is not showing ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error like java.

```
for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
    if(nums[i] == nums[i+1])
        i++;
    else            
        ret.push_back(nums[i]);        
}
```

Comment: is this a c++ question?

Comment: C++ is not Java is the simplest answer.

Comment: C++ is not Java. In C++, when you attempt to access a nonexistent array or vector element through the [] [operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) the result is _undefined behavior_. That means anything at all is valid behavior as far as the language is concerned. Throwing an exception, reading garbage from memory, segfaulting, appearing to work as though your code was correct--all equally valid results from C++'s perspective.

Comment: If you are using [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)s then [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) does not perform bounds checking. Use [`vector<T>::at(size_t)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2079303

Comment: The implementations can be extremely varied between Java and C++.  They are not the same language (for one issue, they have different containers and the containers are implemented differently).

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) for the `operator[]` for `std::vector`:

> No bounds checking is performed.

and

> Accessing a nonexistent element through this operator is undefined behavior.

The alternative, with bounds checking, is the [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) function, which can throw a `std::out_of_range` exception. Using this function is safer, but also slightly slower.

Here, it appears that Java prioritizes safety whereas C++ leaves the choice up to the programmer.